# How to parse hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

***Hash map contains data for example***

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("12");
list.add("12");
list.add("12");
list.add("12");
list.add("12");
list.add("12");

for(int a= 0; a<10; a++){
   map.put(String.valueOf(a), list);
}
```

***How to parse it in adapter and get data as per index of hashmap . I want to show it in recyclerview***

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                   Map.Entry<String, List<Photo>> map = (Map.Entry<String, List<Photo>>) photoMap.get(position);

       List<Photo> photoList = photoMap.get(position);
       String dateTaken = photoMap.entrySet().toString();
       holder.lblTakenDate.setText(dateTaken);

       Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + dateTaken);
       Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + photoList);

       setRecyclerView(holder, context, photoList);
     }

       private void setRecyclerView(ViewHolder holder, Context context, List<Photo> photoList){
               photoCategoryAdapter = new PhotoCategoryAdapter(photoList, context, (OnFileClick) context);
               holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 4));
           }
```

Comment: you can think of a map as json, key value pair. so you can convert the map to a json object, and parse that way

Comment: I don't see the purpose of you OnBindViewHolderMethod !?. Is it incomplete?

Comment: onBindViewHolderMethod is used to bind key as a header and values are pass to another adapter